# Python Format Date issue

Tags: python, django

Something which I thought would be simple has become such a struggle.
I'm trying to format a datetime object.

```
From this 2016-06-17 09:56:53.289000+00:00 to 2016-06-17 09:56:53
```

This code I tried doesn't make any changes to the output. It skips right past it.

```
if type(field) is models.DateField:
   if old_value != None:
      old_value = old_value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')[:-3]
   if new_value != None:
      new_value = new_value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')[:-3]
```

Then I tried the following

```
 if isinstance(new_value, datetime.datetime):
    new_value = new_value.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')[:-3]
 if isinstance(old_value, datetime.datetime):
    old_value = old_value.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')[:-3]
```

However it removes any trace of the values of both new_value and old_value and displays nothing. Which is confusing me so much!

The end part of my code is as follows which displays the date:

```
 if new_value != old_value:
    print "%s does not match" % key
    changes[key] = "Field %s %s updated to %s<br/>" % (key, old_value, new_value)
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: I think this will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `.utcnow()` call you added before your `.strftime()` calls. `new_value.utcnow()` invokes `datetime.datetime.utcnow`, which returns an entirely new datetime.datetime object representing the current time, which has nothing to do with `new_value` or `old_value`.

Comment: The whole day wasting my time on this and you find my mistake in 2 seconds! Thank you!

Comment: Happens to all of us! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
d = '2016-06-17 09:56:53.289000+00:00'

print(datetime.strptime(d[:19], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple snippet based on your code

```
In [11]: from datetime import datetime

In [12]: mytime = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

In [13]: print(mytime)
2016-06-21 16:44:32
```